# Missing sidebar and menu bar in VS Code - how to restore the layout?

Tags: visual-studio-code, layout

[Here's a screenshot of what I'm seeing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6xuwY.png).

How to restore the basic layout of vs code. Accidentally the sidebar and menu bar is hidden. I am unable to access anything. Please help me out from this issue.

I did not find sidebar, menu bar and other functionalities.

Answer (score 1):

You may click on the "Customize layout.." button and then view/hide/restore the appropriate bars as shown in below screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to restoring the default workspace?

If so, according to VS Code Documentation:

> You can always reset a setting to the default value by hovering over a setting to show the gear icon, clicking on the gear icon, and then selecting the Reset Setting action.

You can read more on that [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#:%7E:text=You%20can%20always%20reset%20a,selecting%20the%20Reset%20Setting%20action.)

Answer (score 0):

You can reset view locations using the `View: Reset View Locations` command in the [command palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette).

For the missing menu, check your user [settings.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settingsjson) file and look for a line that modifies the `"window.menuBarVisibility"` property. I suspect you have accidentally set it to `"hidden"`. You can either change the value to whatever you want, or remove that line to cause the default value of the setting to be used.